How to pipeline custom function call with dedicated input?
I created a small NLP model with Scikit-Learn and RandomForest step-by-step and it worked very well. The catch is I have to include additionnal data input in the middle of my pipeline and then package this pipeline with joblib for deployment purposes.
My code is the following:
# Vectorizing preprocessed data (step 1)
x = vectorizer.transform(df.cleaned)
# Reducing dimensions (step 2)
x_reduced = svd.transform(x)
# Merging with other data (not in pipeline, should be step 3)
x_reduced = np.c_[x_reduced, df.other_data.values]
# Compute predictions with random forest (final step)
predictions = rf.predict_proba(x_reduced)[:,1]

I know how to pipeline the vectorizer, the reducer and then the randomforest, but I struggle to figure how to include my numpy.c_ call with custom input.
Both inputs are in the same dataframe so I believe it is possible, maybe with set_params and a custom feature?
Thanks!
